# How do I update the Scheduling End Date on multiple pages?

Tags: quick-edit, bulk, expiration

SharePoint 2013 problem I hope you can help with.

I need to renew a large number of pages in one go, as quickly and easily as possible.

The Quick Edit function allows me to change our date columns except the Scheduling End Date.

I want to avoid having to go into each individual page.

Is there a way to bulk update the Scheduling End Date for multiple pages in SP or SP Designer?

Comment: You could use CSOM or Powershell to bulk update pages.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't used former and don't have latter. Think SPD will do it?

Answer (score 0):

Solution found in SPD.

Set two new columns in my list - new date and trigger

Created workflow based on "If trigger = Y then set scheduling end date to new date"

Answer (score 0):

Ive got the same issue but for documents rather than pages. Could you give me a bit of info on what you did? Specifically around what the "If trigger function does.

Thanks.

Comment: This should work in the same way for docs as it does for pages - I'm assuming you've set versioning/approval/scheduling.

Create two columns, one for your new expiry date (date & time) and another column which will be your trigger for the workflow (single line of text).

The idea is that whenever you enter some text (a 'Y' say) in the trigger column, the date you've entered in the 'new expiry date' column will be used to update the scheduling end date.

So, using SharePoint Designer I have a simple workflow that says 'if trigger is set to 'Y' then schedule end date = new expiry date.